# Issues Comparing Different Timestamps

Tags: php, rest, date, timestamp

I'm using the Binance REST API to get previous trade information:

Endpoint: https://api.binance.com/api/v1/trades?symbol=BTCUSDT

```
$btc_trades = file_get_contents('https://api.binance.com/api/v1/trades?symbol=BTCUSDT');
$btc_trades = json_decode($btc_trades, true);

$five_minutes_ago = strtotime('-5 minutes');
echo "five minutes ago: " . $five_minutes_ago . "<br><br>";

foreach ($btc_trades as $btc_trade) {

    $btc_trade_time = strtotime($btc_trade['time']);
    $btc_trade_total = $btc_trade['qty'] * $btc_trade['price'];

    if ($btc_trade_time >= $five_minutes_ago) { 

        $btc_trade_time = $btc_trade['time'];

        echo "Time: " . $btc_trade_time . "<br>";
        echo "Qty: " . $btc_trade['qty'] . "<br>";
        echo "Price: $" . $btc_trade['price'] . "<br>";
        echo "Total: " . $btc_trade_total . "<br><br>";

    }

}
```

I can confirm by testing that there are trades returned that meet the condition (happened less than five minutes ago) however nothing is returned in this case.

Are the timestamps formatted differently? It seems as if I have everything correct.

From Binance API (https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md):

All time and timestamp related fields are in milliseconds.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you want trades that are greater than 5 minutes ago you need to change `$btc_trade_time >= $five_minutes_ago` to `$btc_trade_time < $five_minutes_ago`

Comment: sorry, I mean less than five minutes ago. I updated the wording in the question.

Comment: It looks like the API trade time is in hundredths of a second, so you should change `$btc_trade_time = strtotime($btc_trade['time'])` to `$btc_trade_time = $btc_trade['time']/100`

Comment: Thanks, but I still get trades that occurred greater than 5 minutes ago

Comment: Sorry, should have been milliseconds and divide by 1000...

Comment: that fixed it. thanks @Nick!

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
$btc_trade_time = $btc_trade['time']/1000
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.